# Encriptación DES, pregunta sobre la funcion DESCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#

Hola estaba estudiando un código de un programa que deshace no sé muy bien como la encriptación DES usando la función DESCryptoServiceProvider.
El código es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Update
{
    class Helper
    {

        internal static bool UrlExists(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                //Creating the HttpWebRequest
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
                //Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
                request.Method = "HEAD";
                //Getting the Web Response.
                HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                //Returns TRUE if the Status code == 200
                response.Close();
                return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            catch
            {
                //Any exception will returns false.
                return false;
            }
        }

        internal static string GetSizeFile(string FileName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName) || !File.Exists(FileName))
                return null;
            double GlobalSize = new FileInfo(FileName).Length;

            if (GlobalSize < 1024)
                return (GlobalSize).ToString() + " Byte";
            else if (1024 <= GlobalSize && GlobalSize < (1024 * 1024))
                return Math.Round((GlobalSize / 1024), 2).ToString() + " KB";
            else if ((1024 * 1024) <= GlobalSize && GlobalSize < (1024 * 1024 * 1024))
                return Math.Round((GlobalSize / (1024 * 1024)), 2).ToString() + " MB";
            else
                return Math.Round((GlobalSize / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)), 2).ToString() + " GB";
        }

        internal static bool isAlreadyInList(ListView AnyList, string FileName)
        {
            foreach (var item in AnyList.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>())
            {
                if (item.Text == FileName)
                    return true;
                foreach (var sub in item.SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>())
                {
                    if (sub.Text == FileName)
                        return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        internal static string GenerateString(int length)
        {
            Random rdm = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
            string[] AllString = Properties.Resources.List_String.Split(' ');
            string sResult = "";
            for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
            {
                sResult += AllString[rdm.Next(AllString.Length)] + " ";
            }
            return sResult;
        }

        internal static string Cr(string File)
        {
            return (char)34 + File + (char)34;
        }

        internal static bool isDotNET(string FileName)
        {
            try
            {
                var asm = Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom(FileName);
                asm = null;
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        internal static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
        {
            MemoryStream memout = new MemoryStream();
            using (MemoryStream memin = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                using (CryptoStream crypto = new CryptoStream(memin, new DESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateDecryptor(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("87654321"), new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("12345678")), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (DeflateStream stream = new DeflateStream(crypto, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                        int numRead;
                        while ((numRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                        {
                            memout.Write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return memout.ToArray();
        }

        internal static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com"))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Lo que no entiendo muy bien es como por medio de esta función deshace la encriptación DES y me devuelve el fichero original. El fichero es simplemente un fichero encriptado con la encriptación DES. si convierto a txt podeis ver el cifrado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta como por medio de este código estoy obteniendo el fichero descifrado si según tengo entiendo la encriptación DES necesita de una clave para descifrar mi fichero??

Answer (score 0):

Es que efectivamente estas dando la clave para desencriptar cuando llamas esta instrucción:

```
using (CryptoStream crypto = new CryptoStream(memin, new DESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateDecryptor(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("87654321"), new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("12345678")), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
```

Tu rgbKey es "87654321" y rgbIV es "12345678"

Revisa lo que hace esa instrucción aquí:

[Método DESCryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/0dh224hh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Saludos